# Disable https and change port for SKyDNS

Tags: kubernetes, skydns

I currently have SkyDNS that is trying to connect via HTTPS and is using port `443`.

```
I1221 01:15:28.199437       1 server.go:91] Using https://10.100.0.1:443 for kubernetes master
I1221 01:15:28.199440       1 server.go:92] Using kubernetes API <nil>
I1221 01:15:28.199637       1 server.go:132] Starting SkyDNS server. Listening on port:10053
```

I want it to use HTTP and port 8080 instead.

My YAML file is :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ReplicationController
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    k8s-app: kube-dns
    version: v18
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        k8s-app: kube-dns
        kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"
        version: v18
    spec:
      containers:
      - args:
        - --domain=kube.local
        - --dns-port=10053
        image: gcr.io/google_containers/kubedns-amd64:1.6
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: kubedns
        ports:
        - containerPort: 10053
          name: dns-local
          protocol: UDP
        - containerPort: 10053
          name: dns-tcp-local
          protocol: TCP
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 200Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 100Mi
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
      - args:
        - --cache-size=1000
        - --no-resolv
        - --server=127.0.0.1#10053
        image: gcr.io/google_containers/kube-dnsmasq-amd64:1.3
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: dnsmasq
        ports:
        - containerPort: 53
          name: dns
          protocol: UDP
        - containerPort: 53
          name: dns-tcp
          protocol: TCP
        resources: {}
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
      - args:
        - -cmd=nslookup kubernetes.default.svc.kube.local 127.0.0.1 >/dev/null &&
          nslookup kubernetes.default.svc.kube.local 127.0.0.1:10053 >/dev/null
        - -port=8080
        - -quiet
        image: gcr.io/google_containers/exechealthz-amd64:1.0
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: healthz
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
          protocol: TCP
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 10m
            memory: 20Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 10m
            memory: 20Mi
```

I understand this might not be a favorable design but is there a way I can change the protocol and port ?

Answer (score 0):

Adding the below like to the kubedns's spec.containers.args section did the trick.

```
 - --kube-master-url=http://master:8080
```